# Schedule data loader

Tags: data-loader, automation, commandline

Below is my bat file which is used to schedule data export from data loader but on running this I am getting "The system cannot find the path specified" error.

```
@echo off
SET DLPATH=”C:\Program Files\salesforce.com\Data Loader”
SET DLCONF=”C:\Users\abcdef\Desktop\CLIDataloader”

REM Initiating the BatchLoad
REM AccountExtract
CALL %DLPATH%\Java\bin\java.exe -cp %DLPATH%\dataloader-28.0.1-uber.jar -Dsalesforce.config.dir=%DLCONF%  com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner process.name=AccountExtract

Exit
```

Below code is working but I want to make my file more dynamic like file name based on date

```
@echo off
CD C:\Program Files\salesforce.com\Data Loader\bin
process.bat "C:\Users\abcdef\Desktop\CLIDataloader" AccountExtract
```

Comment: What I particularly notice between the two files above is that the first line of your 2nd file uses a CD to change directories. I don't see that in your 1st file. The missing path could be in your Java path. Check your environment settings.

Comment: My 1st file is based on this blog: https://gaganbansalblog4u.com/2013/08/15/schedule-data-loader-in-salesforce/

Comment: Do you have the multiple Java beans files too? If not, what you have isn't going to work. That isn't a plain bat file.

Comment: What do you mean by multiple java beans file?

Comment: In the post you linked to, the entire 2nd paragraph: `Remember: You need to have SDL files for all objects and upgrade the Process-Conf file with multiple beans.`  Then he starts the `Example of a Process-Conf XML file for multiple processes.` which contains the beans references. That's what I mean.